# Showing Prism modules inside Prism Module

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism, prism-4

I am implementing application in PRISM, which need to import modules dynamically from dll files.
I managed to do that - they are importing, but I can't display it.
I decided to create a special module to encapsulate it - let us call it ModuleDock.
So we have something like that:

Bootstrapper.cs:

```
class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        var modules = new DirectoryModuleCatalog
        {
            LoadSubdirectories = true,
            ModulePath = @"C:\Modules"
        };

        modules.AddModule(typeof(ModuleDockModule));

        return modules;
    }
}
```

Shell.xaml:

```
<ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="ModuleDockModule" />
```

ModuleDockModule.cs (in ModuleDock project):

```
public class ModuleDockModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private readonly IUnityContainer _unityContainer;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        RegisterIoc();
        if (_regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName("ModuleDockModule"))
        {
            _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ModuleDockModule", typeof(ModuleDockView));
        }
    }

    public ModuleDockModule(IRegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer unityContainer, IRegionViewRegistry regionViewRegistry)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _unityContainer = unityContainer;
    }

    private void RegisterIoc()
    {
        _unityContainer.RegisterType<IModuleDockView, ModuleDockView>();

        _unityContainer.RegisterType<IModuleDockViewModel, ModuleDockViewModel>();
    }
```

}

and finally in one of loaded modules:

```
[Module(ModuleName = "TestModule", OnDemand = false)]
public class TestModuleModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private readonly IUnityContainer _unityContainer;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        RegisterIoc();
        if (_regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName("TestModule"))
        {
            _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TestModule", typeof(TestView));
        }
    }

    public TestModuleModule(IRegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _unityContainer = unityContainer;
    }

    private void RegisterIoc()
    {
        _unityContainer.RegisterType<ITestView, TestView>();

        _unityContainer.RegisterType<ITestViewModel, TestViewModel>();
    }
}
```

For test purposes I've created that line of XAML:

```
<ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="TestModule" />
```

Could you tell me, why that line displays TestModule in Shell.xaml, but don't display it in ModuleDockView.xaml?

Please, mind that in final stage I have to use various number of unknown modules provided by other users of my platform, so I can't make anything static (like module names or initializations).
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In order to confirm, are you asking why TestModule is not displayed in ModuleDockView, but instead in Shell? That would depend in which Xaml page you define that Region with the content Control. Regarding static initializations, they would be made inside each module. So you would not need to worry about that. I would think of making default RegionNames defined in a enum class which everyone would be aware of them.

Comment: @GOstrowsky - no. TestModule is not displayed in ModuleDockView - but I know there is everything correct with loading it, because if I put the same region in Shell.xaml and remove it from ModuleDockView.xaml (for test purposes) it is displaying.

From other side - I am using class with static strings for region names, but for stack I made example with text values for better readability.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The problem would stand on the Module's loading order, as the ***TestModule*** depends on ***ModuleDockModule*** for the ***ModuleDockModule*** region. Could you check if the ***TestModule*** is initializing before the ***ModuleDockModule***? If so, then you would need to add a dependency attribute to ***TestModuleModule*** class as **[ModuleDependency("ModuleDockModule")]**, below the module name attribute. Regards.

Comment: @GOstrowsky - great answer. I would be glad, if you answer me (not comment) and I will mark your answer as a solution of my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code you described, the **TestModule** module has a module dependency with **ModuleDockModule** as this is defining the region that the **TestModule's Views** would then be registered into.

Therefore, you would need to make sure that **ModuleDockModule** is initialized before **TestModule** and any other module that would depend on it. In order to do this, you would need to declare a dependency attribute on **TestModuleModule** class, right above the class definition as follows:

```
[Module(ModuleName = "TestModule", OnDemand = false)]
[ModuleDependency("ModuleDockModule")]
public class TestModuleModule : IModule
{ ...
```

For more information about Moduled you may refer to the following **MSDN Prism Guide** chapter:

- [Modular Application Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

I hope this helped you, Regards.